# How do I print my array based on the output that I want? Row by Row

Tags: java, arrays, println

I need some help to print the arrays row by row but it's 2 different array...

Currently My codes allows me to print all the names, follow by scores, follow by average scores and grade. However I would need to output them based on the student's name and score.. Take a look at the picture for example...

> Current situation : [Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMahw.jpg)
>
> Expected output.. : [Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz63r.jpg)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // 1D Array for Student Names
        String[] names = new String[10];

        //2D Array for test score
        double[][] scores = new double[10][5];

        //1D Array for grades
        char[] grades = new char[5];

        getNames(names);
        getScores(scores);

        print1Array(names);
        print2Array(scores);

        calculateAvg(scores);

        classAvg(scores, names);

    } // PSVMain

    // Using FOR loop to read and store each name 
    public static void getNames(String[] data) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Student names : ");

            data[r] = kb.next();
        } // For R
    } // getInput

    // Using FOR loop to read and store each scores
    public static void getScores(double[][] data) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
            System.out.println("Enter number for row " + (r + 1));

            for (int c = 0; c < data[r].length; c++) {
                System.out.println("Enter number for column " + (c + 1));
                data[r][c] = kb.nextInt();

            } // For C
        } // For R
    } // getInput

    public static void classAvg(double[][] data, String[] name) {

        double[] allAverage = new double[data.length];

        double totalAvg = 0;
        double classAvg = 0;
        double average = 0;

        for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
            double total = 0;

            for (int c = 0; c < data[r].length; c++) {
                total = total + data[r][c];
            } // For C

            average = total / data[r].length;

            // This is the Average for each ROW
            allAverage[r] = average;

            totalAvg = totalAvg + allAverage[r];

        } // For R

        classAvg = (totalAvg / name.length);

        System.out.println("The class Average score is : " + classAvg);

    } // classAvg

    // This method will calculate the Average and assigning Grades
    public static void calculateAvg(double[][] data) {
        double[] allAverage = new double[data.length];
        char[] allGrades = new char[data.length];

        double average = 0;

        for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
            double total = 0;

            for (int c = 0; c < data[r].length; c++) {
                total = total + data[r][c];
            } // For C

            average = total / data[r].length;

            // This is the Average for each ROW
            allAverage[r] = average;

            if (average >= 85 && average <= 100) {
                allGrades[r] = 'A';
            } else if (average >= 75 && average <= 84) {
                allGrades[r] = 'B';
            } else if (average >= 65 && average <= 74) {
                allGrades[r] = 'C';
            } else if (average >= 50 && average <= 64) {
                allGrades[r] = 'D';
            } else if (average < 50) {
                allGrades[r] = 'F';
            } // If

            // Print each ROWS average
            System.out.println("The average for this row is : " + average);

            // Print each ROWS grades
            System.out.println("The Grades for this row is : " + allGrades[r]);

            System.out.println();

        } // For R

    } // Grades

    // This method allows it to print 1D Array
    public static void print1Array(String[] data) {

        for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {

            System.out.print("The student names are " + data[r] + "   ");

            System.out.println();

        } // For R

    } //print 1D Array

    // This method allows it to print 2D Array
    public static void print2Array(double[][] data) {

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("This are the respective student's score");

        for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {

            for (int c = 0; c < data[r].length; c++) {

                System.out.print(data[r][c] + "   ");
            } // For C

            System.out.println();
        } // For R

    } // Print 2D Array
```

Comment: Just as a sidenode, you could create a class `Student` to store each Student data, this way you wouldn´t have multiple arrays just connected by theyr index to represent a `Student`. In there you could easily implement methods to seperatly print the student data aswell, which in fact you could use here.

Comment: use one loop to print both the arrays

Comment: Your design uses what is known as "parallel arrays". This is a strong anti-pattern, i.e. a design that is to be avoided at all costs, especially in an object-oriented language such as Java.  It is left over from the 1960s when there were no data types in Fortran other than arrays.  Take @KevinEsche's suggestion and define a class to hold all information for a Student instead.

Comment: Thanks for your advise guys.. But I was taught in a way to use it this way.. Maybe for my next program I should do it in one method..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This pseudo code might help you in achieving desired result

```
For i=0 till names.length
   print names[i]
   total=0
   For j=0 till scores[i].length
      print scores[i][j]
      total=total+scores[i][j]
   End For
   Print Average = total/scores[i].length;
   decide Grade on basis of average and print
End For
```

Comment: Sorry, have to downvote because parallel arrays is a bad anti-pattern.  No answer should support their use.

Comment: Thats ok @JimGarrison. Icompletely agree with you and having a Student Object with all related values is a right solution. I did not wanted to put an answer on someone else idea thats why i gave this alternate solution. By the way questions with anti-patterns shall also not be allowed. right?

Comment: Should I create a new method according to this pseudo code?? Where should I put this logic into which method?? Sorry.. I'm very new to array and java..

Comment: That's your choice, you can put this in a new method or replace any of your existing method, which will take names and scores array as input.

Comment: Really thanks for your help Sanjeev, after looking through the pseudocode multiple times, I finally understood... Cheers!! @Sanjeev

Comment: Glad that helped you .. have fun coding :)